# difference in web hosting when it comes to developers

Tags: html, web-services, web-applications, web

hi guys i am not sure how to properly explain this but ive been trying to find an answer and really there is nothing available.

what i am trying to ask is

what is the differwnce between a web hosting company like godaddy vs a self hosted server something like ebay amazon facebook uses

and how does this relate to developers.

where do major comapnies like ebay and facebook get their hosting companies in comparison to a smaller type home retailer using godaddy

Answer (score 0):

I know one difference is that is you use a site like GoDaddy you can put up a website coded in asp.Net because their servers have IIS on them. If you were to host your own site you would have to either buy a license from Microsoft or write your page in another language like PHP.

Having your site hosted somewhere else usually also limits you to a finite amount of server storage space and bandwidth, but also prevents you from having to deal with the maintenance issues that might come up if you hosted your own site

I know amazon cloud services are pretty popular, even with large companies